# Is there a different method to use templatized structs in clang9 than in gcc7 or gcc11?

Tags: constructor, c++17, clang, parameter-passing

The following error was encountered in clang9 build of the project:

```
project/csrc/pytorchbridge/aot_ops/meta_op_launch.h:85:1: error: member reference base type 'metaop_variable' is not a structure or union DEFINE_LAUNCH_METAOP(scaled_dot_product_attention) ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

project/csrc/pytorchbridge/aot_ops/meta_op_launch.h:56:44: note: expanded from macro 'DEFINE_LAUNCH_METAOP' return at::metaop(metaop_variable(args).value...); \
```

Analysis: There is one template structure defined at the top of the file like this:

```
template <typename T>
struct aten_variable_info {
    aten_variable_info(const T& var, const c10::ScalarType&, const std::string& name) {
        std::stringstream ss;
        ss << "{\n" << var << "\n}\n";
        info = name + ": " + ss.str() + "\n";
    }
    std::string info;
};
```

Then for specialized cases template structures are defined without any template type defined, for example:

```
template <>
struct aten_variable_info<c10::optional<at::Tensor>> {
    aten_variable_info(const c10::optional<at::Tensor>& opt_tensor, const c10::ScalarType&, const std::string& name) {
        info = name + ": " + tensorToString(opt_tensor) + "\n";
    }
    std::string info;
};
```

At different calls of the struct, according to the data passed to the struct(which is called inside a macro defintion in most cases), different structs are accessed through these templates with the help of paramter pack args,which provides a method to provide 0 or more arguments to the struct.

In the case of gcc7 and gcc11 builds, this is causing no issues.

Is there a different method of accessing the value member of above defined struct that should be used for clang9 or preferably one that is compatible with both gcc and clang builds ?

To fix this, the following methods were tried:

Method 1: Created an auto variable for the struct call and tried to use it in the macro definition:
auto meta_op_variable_struct = metaop_variable(args...);

Usage:
return at::metaop(meta_op_variable_struct.value);

This caused the error : No viable constructor or deduction method was found for the call : auto meta_op_variable_struct = metaop_variable(args...);

Method 2: Used -fclang-abi-compat=9 clang flag for build instead of -fabi-version=11 which was used in the gcc build as this flag is not supported by clang9. The original error still occurred.

The code snippets contain the definition of templatized structs and its specializations.

Is there a method to access the value member of aten_variable_info struct as defined in above code snippets,that could be compatible with both clang9 and gcc builds?

Is the code inherently faulty?